# How to get structured list values from unmanaged c++ code to c#?

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, marshalling

I'm writing "ICS/VCS" file parser in win32 c++.

After deserialization from a file, I am storing event data inside a list of event struct.

Now I want to access that structured list in c#. 
For that, I have exported function and list in DLL.

I don't know how to access that list in c#.

Here is my event struct:

```
struct Event {
Event(): Alarms(new list<Alarm>), RecurrenceNo(0), BaseEvent(this) {}
Event(const Event &Base) :
    UID(Base.UID),
    Organizer(Base.Organizer),
    Summary(Base.Summary),
    Description(Base.Description),
    Attendee(),
    Categories(Base.Categories),
    DtStamp(Base.DtStamp),
    DtStart(Base.DtStart),
    DtEnd(Base.DtEnd),
    RRule(Base.RRule),
    Alarms(Base.Alarms),
    AttendeeCounter(Base.AttendeeCounter),
    RecurrenceNo(Base.RecurrenceNo)

{
    BaseEvent = Base.BaseEvent == (Event *)&Base ? (Event *)&Base : Base.BaseEvent;
}
~Event() {
    if (BaseEvent == this)
        delete Alarms;
}
operator string() const;
bool HasAlarm(const Date &From, const Date &To);

string UID, Summary, Description, Categories, Attendee[100], Organizer;
int AttendeeCounter=0;
Date DtStamp, DtStart, DtEnd;
Recurrence RRule;
list<Alarm> *Alarms;
unsigned short RecurrenceNo;
Event *BaseEvent;
};
```

Here is the **ExportFunction.h**

```
extern list <Event *> ListofAllEvents;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) list <Event *> ParseCalendar(std::string FilePath);
```

Here is the function that I'm exporting 
"**ExportFunction.cpp**"

```
list <Event *> ParseCalendar(std::string FilePath)
{
const char * InputPath = FilePath.c_str();

ICalendar Calendar(InputPath);
return ListofAllEvents;
}
```

Here is the Program.cs

```
    [DllImport("D:\\Projects\\iCalander\\x64\\Debug\\iCalander.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr ParseCalendar(string FilePath);
```

It shows an access violation error. which is expected because I'm not accessing correctly.

I'm new to pInvoke and marshaling.

Comment: google for ""std::string" C# interop" ... the right answer is you shouldn't do this (expose std::string to C#) ... pass plain `(w)char*` ... edit: also you should not expose any std C++ object (like std::list)

Comment: I thought that too. But I need to access parsed content in my c# application. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: For the string parameter, you must use `char*` or `wchar_t*` (or `BSTR`). For the object, sure you can return an opaque pointer to C# but what will you do with it then? You can think of it as if C# was seeing C++ code as C (pointers, base types, structures, etc. no class). Think binary layout.

Comment: I am only using string to get the file path from c#. I'm using char* internally within c++ application. It is because of CLR I had to use string.

Comment: @SimonMourier can you point me somewhere on how can I access the list? I want to perform db operation inside c# application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for future reference if anyone wants to do the same.

I followed this tutorial to experiment and learn about interop.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/creating-ccli-wrapper/

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/.net-framework/5-tips-for-understanding-managed-unmanaged-interoperability-in-.net/?_ga=2.110977479.318099589.1504532675-232460203.1501855788

Then I implemented event struct's prototype class into c++/cli.

```
public ref class iCalendarEvent 
{
public:
    String ^mUID;
    String ^mOrgaizer;
    String ^mSummary;
    String ^mDescription;
    String ^mCategories;
    String ^mDtStart;
    String ^mDtEnd;
    String ^mDtStamp;
    cli::array<String ^>^ mAttendee = gcnew cli::array<String ^>(100);
    int mAttendeeLength;

};
```

Then created a Generic list of type iCalendarEvent. Then I mapped each event object returned from c++ into class obj from c++/cli and inserted it into the generic list of c++/CLI.